# Jmeter - Cookies not in the Headers as They are in Browser

Tags: apache, jmeter, load-testing

I am new to Jmeter and load testing overall but I have read about the Cookie Manager over and over and still can't find the answer to my problem.

The site I am trying to test uses several cookies to authenticate but not all of them are seen in the Jmeter Response Headers. I can see them if I look using the browser but Jmeter doesn't seem to pick them up at all.

If I manually set the cookies in the Cookie Manager after a recent session then the test passes but my concern is that when I use multiple threads, they won't all get individual values and rather just the ones I have specified.

I expect all the cookies that are set to be displayed in the response headers, that way I can set variables etc but out of 3 only one appears in Jmeter.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the below information:-

> JMeter checks that received cookies are valid for the URL. This means
>   that cross-domain cookies are not stored. If you have bugged behaviour
>   or want Cross-Domain cookies to be used, define the JMeter property
>   "**CookieManager.check.cookies=false"**.
>
> Received Cookies can be stored as JMeter thread variables. To save
>   cookies as variables, define the property
>   **"CookieManager.save.cookies=true"**. Also, cookies names are prefixed
>   with "COOKIE_" before they are stored (this avoids accidental
>   corruption of local variables) To revert to the original behaviour,
>   define the property "CookieManager.name.prefix= " (one or more
>   spaces). If enabled, the value of a cookie with the name TEST can be
>   referred to as **${COOKIE_TEST}.**

You can find these setting under JmeterFolder/bin/jmeter.properties file.

For more information:-
[Cookie Manager](http://Ref:-https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)

Kindly check if this helps.